# dynamic_cast doesn't guarantee a valid, complete object?

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I was reading on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) and it says

> dynamic_cast can be used only with pointers and references to objects. Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type conversion is a valid complete object of the requested class.

But dynamic_cast doesn't give a valid object when I do this:

```
struct A{};
struct B:A{};
void main(){
    A a;
    B b;
    B* bPtr = (B*) 0x0000001;
    A* aPtr = dynamic_cast<A*>(bPtr);
    //Now aPtr is the memory address 0x00000001
}
```

Since the bPtr does not contain a valid A object, I would expect dynamic_cast to fail this cast so that aPtr would get NULL. But this is not happening? Which one is wrong, the compiler (g++ 4.5.7) or the above mentioned web page? Or am I missing something about what dynamic_cast is actually supposed to do?

**Edit: Answer Summary**

1. In upcast, dynamic_cast does nothing. There is no guarantee of any sort.
2. In downcast, dynamic_cast does not check for bad pointers. It assumes that the source pointer either is 0 or points to a valid source object. (the dynamic_cast operation can segfault during a downcast if it is given a bad pointer)
3. Downcast through dynamic_cast requires at least one virtual member in the base class.

Comment: You're answer summary to paragraph 1 is wrong. If you cast a pointer to derived class to a pointer to an unambiguous base class the result is _guaranteed_ to be a pointer to the valid base class of the derived object to which the souce pointer was pointing.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, I think in point-1, @neuron meant there is no RTTI happens while converting from Derived to base (as it's a trivial operation), for which the `dynamic_cast<>` is typically intended.

Comment: @iammilind: But it doesn't do "nothing" even in this trivial case. It will do the correct pointer adjustments to make the result valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_cast<>` is guaranteed to give a valid object, provided that it's used properly.

The very *1st requirement* to use this cast is to have **polymorphic base class** (at least 1 `virtual` function). In your example, `A` and `B` are not polymorphic and it will result in compilation error.

The *2nd requirement* is that `dynamic_cast<>` should be used for downcasting, in your case you are using it for upcast (which happens trivially).

Suppose, they were polymorphic then the *3rd requirement* is to use this casting on a  pointer/reference to a proper object.
`bPtr = (B*)0x0000001` is not guaranteed to refer an object (mostly it's a UB) of `B`.

Here is the correct example:

```
struct A{ virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : A {};
void main(){
  A* pA = new B;
  B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when doing a upcast, dynamic_cast does no RTTI check, so there is no guarantee whatsoever; and that RTTI is checked only in downcast, which requires the presence of a virtual member (so that RTTI info may be located)?

Comment: @neuron, yes RTTI is meant for downcasting. Because, derived class to base class is default convertible (assume `public` inheritance); but the otherwise is not true.

Comment: The 2nd requirement is bogus. A `dynamic_cast` can be used to cast from pointer or reference to a derived class to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous bas class (in this the source class type does not have to be polymorphic) or to any unambiguous base class of the type of the complete object being cast.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, I was referring to conventional use of `dynamic_cast` with respect to OP's question. That's the reason I have used *"should"* for 2nd requirement.

Comment: Casting "across" an inheritance hierarchy is also a conventional use of `dynamic_cast` and one where no other single cast will do the job in any circumstance.